# how to export issues retrived from a search filter as xml automatically in JIRA

Tags: php, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I have a customized filter which will give me list of issues.

Currently there is a option to export the filter results to XML. Is there any way to automatically export the XML . Currently i have to export it to XML format every time.

My requirement is to export the search filter to XML using a script.
I want the XML file to be downloaded to my local machine every day at a particular time after that i will process the XML file for my desired operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click the `Export to XML` link while logged into JIRA and choose `Copy Link Address` if you are using Chrome. (Forget what it is in Firefox/IE/Safari/Etc.)

This will give you a link like:

```
https://dev-jira.myhost.com/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/temp/SearchRequest.xml?jqlQuery=project+%3D+test+and+issuetype+%3D+Story&tempMax=1000
```

Then you can use something to just hit that URL to download the results like cURL:

```
curl -o my-output.xml -u myUser:myPassword "https://dev-jira.myhost.com/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/temp/SearchRequest.xml?jqlQuery=project+%3D+test+and+issuetype+%3D+Story&tempMax=1000"
```

If you're using Unix based OS you can set this up on a cron, if you are using windows you could set it up to run using the Task Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I see a difference in XML files when i download manually and when i run using the above script.
Why is it so?

When i download manually i get a proper XML file which is easy for my manipulation.

Comment: I saved both the cURL export and the Chrome export and then compared them using DiffMerge. They both appear to be the same except the top comment has a different time stamp value for the generation time which is to be expected. JIRA does add a unnecessary white space which is what you may be seeing.

Comment: great.. i was able to get it. How to use the same in PHP.